# The complement of a subset of a set (Sigma-algebra creation)

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

So I'm trying to form a sigma-algebra F for the set X = {{1,2,3}, {3,4,5}, {5,6,7}}.

So first thing first is that X itself, aswell as the empty set, is part of the sigma-algebra.

Now since {1,2,3}, {3,4,5} and {5,6,7} is part of F (correct?), then so should their complements. But I'm a bit stuck on how to technically form the complements of sets that are overlapping.

How would I for example form the complement of {1,2,3}? Would one of these be the correct method:

{1,2,3}$^c$ = X \ {1,2,3} = {3,4,5}U{5,6,7} = {3,4,5,6,7}

or

{1,2,3}$^c$ = X \ {1,2,3} = ({3,4,5}U{5,6,7}) \ {1,2,3} = {4,5,6,7}

Or are neither of these correct? Hoping someone can clear up my confusion a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a family of sets $X$, and you want to find the least sigma-algebra containing $X$. Here it is important to remember the definition of a sigma-algebra (see e.g. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sigma-Algebra.html)

A sigma-algebra is a family of sets $\mathcal{F}$ *over some universe* $U$ such that

1. $U \in \mathcal{F}$
2. Let $A\subset U$. If $A \in \mathcal{F}$ then $\overline{A} \in \mathcal{F}$
3. If we have a family of subsets $\{A_i\subset U\}_{i \in I}$, and $A_i \in \mathcal{F}$ for every $i \in I$, where $I$ is some index set (which may be infinite), then $\bigcup_{i \in I} U_i \in \mathcal{F}$

Your confusion stems from a misconception about the underlying universe. The universe is not the family of sets for which we are trying to find its sigma-algebra closure, but the *union* of these sets.

All the sets in your $X$ have elements from the universe $\{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 \}$, so condition 1 above tells us that $\{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 \} \in U$.

The complement of $\{ 1,2,3 \}$ is *relative to the universe*, so $\overline{\{ 1,2,3 \}} = \{ 4,5,6,7 \}$.